# Grass 6 tools missing in Processing tool box

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, osgeo4w

I have installed QGIS via osgeo4w-setup (64Bit). I cannot find grass 6 tools in the toolbox. I also have the dev version of QGIS on my notebook and there I can see and work with the grass 6 tools. Do I have to install something else? [image]

[image]

Comment: Is GRASS 6 enabled in the Processing options?

Comment: Only grass7 path.

Comment: Please add information about your installed QGIS version

Comment: Sorry, I was not available the last days. I figured out that only the osgeo4w-installation causes the issue. After installing the regular setup (full version) everything is ok.

Comment: Update: My PC broke and I have downloaded and installed the current version from the qgis webpage (regular 64bit setup) on my new virgin laptop. The grass 6 tools are missing.

Comment: The stand-alone installer only contains one GRASS version, most likely 7 by now.

Comment: Ok. Thank you! I will install a 2.16 and change my models.